# jQuery REST call returns 403 to Office365 SharePoint

Tags: jquery, rest, sharepoint

When I navigate to a REST endpoint (https://snowburnt.sharepoint.com/_api/navigation/menustate for example) in my browser, it gives me expected results.

When I make a jQuery call like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://snowburnt.sharepoint.com/_api/navigation/menustate",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        // Returning the results
        complete(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        failure(data);
    }
    });
```

from the same browser session I get a 403 error.  Why would this happen?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definitely in authentication. 403 code is access denied code. I have tested your code in test page within my own tenant and it works fine.

But even if you open new browser in private mode (to disable cached authorization cookies) and put https://snowburnt.sharepoint.com/_api/navigation/menustate in address bar you will get access denied error.

Comment: I'm aware of the 403 access denied error, but is there any reason it would happen when I have my authentication cached?

Comment: No. Check cookies using Developer tool of your browser and browser settings. Trusted sited in IE could help.